# Jenkins job to read data from SQL DB

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm new to Jenkins. I have a task where I need to create a Jenkins job to automate builds of certain projects. The build job parameters are going to be stored in the SQL database. So, the job would keep querying the DB and it has to load data from the DB and perform the build operation.

Examples would be greatly appreciated.

How can this be done?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to keep job parameters in the SQL database?

Comment: yes, the user would add configuration records from a UI screen, which is then stored in the SQL DB

Comment: I think you are in process of doing automation to automation process.

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform the data from available source to the format expecting by the destination.

Here your source data available in DB and you want to use this data in Jenkins.

There might be numerous ways but the efficient way of reading data is using [EnvyInJect Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

If you were able to provide the whole data as [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0204propertiesfileformat01.html) file format and type to EnvyInject plugin, the whole data is available as environment variables you can use these variable in the Jobs configuration.

EnvyInject Plugin can read this properties file from the Jenkins Job Workspace. And you can provide that file path in Properties File Path input.

[image: EnvyInject Properties File Path]

To read the data from source and make available as properties file.
Either you can write a executable or if your application provides api to download the properties data.

Both ways to be executed before the SCM step, for this you have to use [Pre-SCM-Step](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep)
Get the data and inject the data in pre-scm-step only, so that the data available as environment variables.

This is one thought to give gist for you to start. while implementing you may get lot of thoughts to implement according to your requirement.